# How can capture full screen snapshot from a running game in c#?

Tags: c#, capture

I wrote a program in c# that takes snap shot (print screen) from a running game . when a game is not full screen, all thing is OK but when I do it full screen my program takes snap shot from visual studio environment instead of the game. I tested different code and different way, but my problem didn't solve.
Can anyone guide me?
thanks a lot.

Comment: Please include some code so that we can have a better understanding of what you're doing.

Comment: You will get answers faster if you ask a specific question. By the looks of your question, you need to go and perform some research around the tools that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

[hello, My code is here, please observe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4rij.png)